# Running multiple lines through a server

Tags: voip

I am looking to buy numbers in bulk on DIDx.net. After I purchase the numbers in a particular area code, I want to forward those numbers to other numbers that are outside of that area code. This way it will be seen as a local call versus long distance.

I have the customers but I don't have the system I need. I have read about Asterisk, VOIP, SIP, and BYOH. But I have no clue what will be the best system for me. Does anyone have any idea what my next step should be when it comes to hardware and software? Or what type of operating system I should use? I basically want to set up a system like GoogleVoice & Phonebooth.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to critique your business plan, or your spelling. Do you have any technical talent in your employ? Why would any of us want to help you do this, for free?

Answer (score 3):

Forwarding numbers like that would be trivial in Asterisk.

However the commenter is right.  Sounds like you need a technical person to get this off the ground.  Hire someone.